How to set AbstractConsumerSeekAware on ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory?
I am trying to set a generic MessageListener on ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory like below
@Component
@Slf4j
public class GossiperMessageListener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements
    MessageListener<String, String> {


  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(
      @NotNull Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, @NotNull ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    val groupId = KafkaUtils.getConsumerGroupId();
    log.info("XXXXX groupId: {} assigned partitions: {}", groupId, assignments);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {
    log.info("Received message with Key: {}", data.key());
  }
}

@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

  public static final String AT_LEAST_ONCE_KAFKA_CONTAINER_FACTORY =
      "atLeastOnceKafkaListenerContainerFactory";

  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigBase() {
    val props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:19092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);

    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(
        ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
    props.put(
        ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,
        300000);
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<
      ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>, String, String>
  atLeastOnceKafkaListenerContainerFactory(GossiperMessageListener listener) {
    val factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigBase()));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(listener);
    return factory;
  }
}

I can see that partitions are getting assigned and I can receive messages from Kafka but my custom GossiperMessageListener is not getting invoked. Can someone let me know what is going wrong
2024-06-17T21:54:54.439+05:30  INFO 38597 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : TOPIC_A.group_id: partitions assigned: [TOPIC_A-0]
...

The reproducible code is placed in kafka_exp branch in github. To send a message to Kafka running at the port 19092 in local do
curl --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/hello'

In my actual project, there are many service classes with @KafkaListener listening on different topics. So I am looking for a way to set the ConsumerSeekAware at the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory so that I do not have to modify all service classes with @KafkaListener

spring-kafka - 3.0.12


How do you use that atLeastOnceKafkaListenerContainerFactory? Apparently you also have somewhere @KafkaListener since you got a MessageListenerContainer with those assignment activities. See KafkaListenerContainerFactory to be sure that it is exactly what you need. You definitely can implement AbstractConsumerSeekAware on the service with @KafkaListener.
See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/seek.html

I have edited the question and placed a reproducible code in https://github.com/debraj-manna/spring-boot-hello-world/tree/kafka_exp. I have also mentioned why am I trying to set AbstractConsumerSeekAware at the KafkaListenerContainerFactory level. Please let me know if is even doable.

Right. Every @KafkaListener creates a container and sets itself as a listener into that container. Essentially, overriding whatever you set there via getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(listener);. That's by design. Just because a @KafkaListener is a thing by itself. The ConsumerSeekAware is a listener aspect and it cannot be set globally. Every @KafkaListener has to have its own ConsumerSeekAware. You are feel free to delegate from there to anything what is common.

Ok understood. So that means every service class having @KafkaListener I have to make them extend AbstractConsumerSeekAware In this example KafkaStringConsumer extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware or is there any smarter way of doing this where I do not have to refactor every service class?

Not that I'm aware of. It might be great to hear your story and know why are you pursing a feature which was never considered. I mean that common ConsumerSeekAware. What's the point of it, please?

We have a few cases where we want to seek the offset of consumer groups to specific TopicPartitions (via some admin APIs). As per my understanding, the only way to do this now is via ConsumerSeekAware interface. As I was trying to say the problem that now we are facing is that we have numerous service classes with @KafkaListener and some of them have multiple @KafkaListener methods. So we have to make changes in many places for each of them to extend ConsumerSeekAware.

Right. According to the docs, there is no other way, unless ConsumerSeekAware for every service with @KafkaListener. Also see this for some possible problems with multi-@KafkaListener: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2302
